# Loading an OBJMTL Object with three.js and get geometry parameter of the Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, mesh, vertices

I just load an MTLOBJ and everything is fine but when I want to get the Geometry attribute of the object to get the vertices, there is no way because apparently, it loads a Object3D which should have a Mesh. But I hardly try to find a way to solve this problem.

It seems that Mrdoob proposes to get the parses data but every parameters used in the parse function are set private ..

I try to get the vertices parameters from the geometry parameter which should be in a mesh but no way, even looking through the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the geometry in the hierarchy by doing this:

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.geometry !== undefined ) {

        console.log( child.geometry.vertices );

    }

} );
```

Comment: The result of this for my OBJ is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

After some researchs, it appeared that the **Object3D is composed with Meshs**.

And in the case of loading an OBJMTL (.obj and .mtl), the Object3D named modele had **the Mesh accessible by doing modele.children[O]** and the array vertices of geometry by doing modele.children[0].geometry.vertices .

I was looking for a way to be sure the object I attribute to my modele was the Mesh with his geometry parameter, thank you Mr Doob for that.

```
function loadModel(obj, mtl) {
    loader.load(obj, mtl, function ( object ) {
        modele = object;
        //loadingDone = true;
        analyseModel();
        //putModel();
    });
}

function analyseModel() {
    analyser = new AnalyseObj(modele.children[0]); //I give the Mesh of my model
}
```